P.I. License requirement?
Regarding the drone search and rescue industry in the southern California area. Specifically, using thermal drones to look for lost dogs. I stumbled upon a website https://www.missinganimalresponse.com/mar-courses/ that stated in part

If you plan to offer fee-based services, be aware that a few states (in the USA) have laws that say you must have a private investigator’s license in order to search for lost or stolen pets as a business.

I have two questions regarding this, the second is dependent on the answer of the first, so it may not be relevant:
Does California have this requirement and, if so, what is the reference?
If California does have this requirement AND the operator only accepts donations (as opposed to fixed-fee based), does the PI License requirement still apply?

Are the donations voluntary? I.e. will you do the search even if the client doesn't make a donation? It's not really a donation if the payment is required.

For your second question, yes the donation is completely voluntary. And it the donation would not be requested unless the pet was found.
